# Iterating through each cell in column from bottom up but no changes are being made VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a macros button that when pressed will find the "Roster" worksheet, Activate it, and then iterate through "D" column and replace "Hello" with "HelloWorld". I believe I have the correct code so just wondering where I made a mistake or if their is something I am missing at a Higher level than what I am looking at. Thank!

```
Sub HelloName()
'Add worksheet after data that imports Hellos 


Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Dim Counter1 As Integer


For Each xlsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (xlsheet.Name = "Roster") Then
        xlsheet.Activate

        For Counter1 = 1 To xlsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            If xlsheet.Cells(Counter1, "D").Value = "Hello" Then
                xlsheet.Cells(Counter1, "D").Value = "HelloWorld"
            End If
        Next Counter1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

***EDIT:***
SOLUTION: There was a space before each use of the word! Instead of "Hello" it was   " Hello". It doesn't look like it in the cell so I would click cell with the word and copy paste whatever is up in the top bar. Just to make 100% sure.

Comment: Do you need to loop through the sheets? If you know the sheet name you can just use that sheet. You should also use ```long``` not ```integer``` large sheets have more rows than integer can handle. Lastly you'll need to step through and see what is happening. There are no other issues in the code itself that I can see so it's probably skipping an ```if``` somewhere

Comment: Also you don't need to activate the sheet when using explicit references that line doesn't really do a whole lot.

Comment: Why not just find and replace?

Comment: @SJR My end goal isn't actually finding and replacing, but I am having problems with my end goal and its because of this.

Comment: @Warcupine Thanks. I will try these and get back to you in a hour or so. gtg lol.

Comment: Is it possible that the word you have in those cells is 'hello' and not 'Hello'?

Comment: I've ran your code and it works just as you are describing it should.  You most likely have a typo or your data is not in column "D" or something simple like that.

Comment: @BZngr hmm I will take a step back and look from a wider angle. Thanks!

Comment: @hod It is just example data, but I will triple check it!

Comment: @hod it was ' Hello' instead of 'Hello' lol.